# Showing content from one page on another

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, page-template, the-content

There are many posts that seem to strike around this area, but I'm more and more confused by each one I read.

I have a page that shows the "Terms of Service" (id = 1086).  I would like to display the content of that page inside a template (signup.php) on another page.

I'm running latest version (4.3).  I'm confused by where to put which bit of code.  (functions.php vs right in the template etc...)

How can I show the content of my Terms of Service page on my signup template?

EDIT:
Note the change to the post id.

Using @terminator's advice here is the code that I have on my signup.php page:

```
<div id="termsOfService">
  <?php $my_postid = 1086;//This is page id or post id
        $content_post = get_post($my_postid);
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
        echo $content; ?>
</div> <!-- termsOfService -->
```

This returns an empty string

Here is the permalink and shortlink

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that worked for me was the following:

```
<? $the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=1086' );
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

I found this on a [thread here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/showing-one-pages-content-on-another-page)

Answer (score 1):

It should work

```
<?php
$my_postid = 1772;//This is page id or post id
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: This goes into the template file?  Within a `<?php` tag?

Comment: yup this goes with in the <?php tag and in the template file

Comment: Could something be being stripped out here?  I don't get anything to show up.  I've verified the id by looking at the shortlink, but `$content` is blank.

Comment: @paqogomez  why do you have $outout in get_post()

Comment: Oops, that was just something i tried based on the documentation of `get_post()`.  I tried it both with and without.